# Can one illusionist turn another's illusions against the original caster?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, illusion

This is something that you see in movies (both animated and live action) and books. Two illusionists are battling and change the other's illusions so that the original illusionist himself is affected by it, and then have to wrest control back of it.

This brings up an interesting question: If you had two battling illusionists, can one gain control of another's illusions to turn them against the original caster in the game? If so, how would it work?

Answer (score 3):

There are some ways to wrest control of a spell from the original caster, but I don't know of any that are specific to illusions.

- Seize Concentration and Snatch Spell (both from Incantatrix PrC): Steal control of any spell that allows ongoing control of any kind. Requires an opposed caster level check.
- Steal Summoning (Sor/Wiz6, Complete Mage): Steal the loyalty of a summoned creature. Requires an opposed caster level check.
- Mastery of Counterspelling (Archmage PrC) or Srinshee's Spell Shift (Sor/Wiz9, Lost Empires of Faerun): Whenever you counter a spell, you can re-target it instead of just negating it.
- Ring of Spell-Battle (68k gp, Magic of Faerun): Re-target someone else's spell 1/day.